# Using different images foreach object in one class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a catalog for online shop like ebay. How to make each box with different image and title. Am I supposed to use JS here and if so how to do it?

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  background-color: #E7E7E7;
  font-family: system-ui;
  color: #000;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20rem 1fr;
  margin: 2.6rem;
}

.box {
  border-radius: 3%;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px#bababa;
  width: 15rem;
  height: 17.5rem;
}

.image {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: url(Reference/Shoes/Air\ Jordan\ 1\ Retro\ High\ OG\ Shoes.webp);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 100px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.title {
  margin: 20px 20px 0 20px;
}

.creator {
  color: #525252;
  font-size: 9.5pt;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="title">
      <p>Nike Air Max Jordan 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="creator">
      <p>Martingrgv</p>
    </div>
    <div class="price"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="title">
      <p>Nike Air Max Jordan 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="creator">
      <p>Martingrgv</p>
    </div>
    <div class="price"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Result:
[image: Reference]

I am new to building a website so you might see beginner mistakes.
If you have any suggestions to improve the code I am open.

Comment: You could generate this from an object. It is not clear what you want.

Comment: why you not using an img tag? if you want cover, use `object-fit:cover`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this - you can ajax the object from your server:

```js
const items = [ 
{ image: "nike1.jpg", title:"Nike Air Max Jordan 1",price:150, creator:"Martingrgv"},
{ image: "nike2.jpg", title:"Nike Air Max Jordan 2",price:160, creator:"Martingrgv"}
]
 
 document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = items.map(item =>
   `<div class="box">
    <div class="image"><img src="${item.image}" /></div>
    <div class="title">
      <p>${item.title}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="creator">
      <p>${item.creator}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="price">$${item.price}</div>
  </div>`)
  .join("");
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  background-color: #E7E7E7;
  font-family: system-ui;
  color: #000;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20rem 1fr;
  margin: 2.6rem;
}

.box {
  border-radius: 3%;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px#bababa;
  width: 15rem;
  height: 17.5rem;
}

.image {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 100px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.title {
  margin: 20px 20px 0 20px;
}

.creator {
  color: #525252;
  font-size: 9.5pt;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'd like to ask you why do you exchange class container with id container?

Comment: @Martin This is for targetting it with `document.getElementById`, an id is used to uniquely identify an element, whereas a class is to be apply to potentialy multiple elements. If you want to have several containers on the same page that share some CSS but have different use cases, then use both id (only for the one in which you render the items) and class (for all).

Comment: @Martin If you prefer to keep the .container class, then change the code to `document.querySelector(".container")` - I just prefer to be very specific. If there is only one container, I recommend to use ID